# pd.read_excel in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-3.6

i'm currently using read_excel to access my excel file and i have assigned variables to each column in the work sheet by referring to the first cell object of the column(*column headings in the excel sheet*). Now this works fine and i have been able to sort data in each column just by referring to the variables i assigned. However when i add the sheetname argument to read_excel so as to apply my sorting code to other sheets in the excel file with identical column placements and first cell objects(*column heading in the excel sheet*), i get an error. What do i do?

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
#import os
#import collections
from collections import defaultdict
#import pylab as pl
#import xlrd
import warnings; warnings.simplefilter('ignore')

# reading the excel sheet
df = pd.read_excel('file_path.xlsx') 


# assigning variables to each column
gender = df['Gender']
name = df['Name']
age = df['Age']
district = df['District']
school = df['School']
private_public = df['Is your school']   
settlement_type = df['Type of settlement']
```

i get this error message

*File "C:/Users/qanda/OneDrive/Documents/Python Scripts/PEN/pen_data_man.py", line 25, in 
    gender = df['Gender']
KeyError: 'Gender'*

when i add *sheetname=None*

```
df = pd.read_excel('file_path.xlsx')
```

to

```
df = pd.read_excel('file_path.xlsx', sheetname=None)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, post your code as a text snippet as shown here: [Markdown help —
Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Also post an error you get.

Answer (score 0):

If check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-sheets):

> The arguments sheetname allows specifying the sheet or sheets to read.
>   The default value for sheetname is 0, indicating to read the first sheet
>   Pass a string to refer to the name of a particular sheet in the workbook
>   Pass an integer to refer to the index of a sheet. Indices follow Python convention, beginning at 0.
>   Pass a list of either strings or integers, to return a dictionary of specified sheets.
>   Pass a **None** to return a **dictionary** of all available sheets.

So if add `None` argument get `dictionary` of all `DataFrames` - for each sheetname one `df`:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('multiple_sheets.xlsx', sheetname=None)
print (dfs)
{'sheetname2':    t  w
0  7  1
1  5  0, 'sheetname1':    a  b
0  1  4
1  2  8}

df1 = dfs['sheetname1']
print (df1)
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  8

df2 = dfs['sheetname2']
print (df2)
   t  w
0  7  1
1  5  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much jezrael, but i would want my sorting code to iterate through all the sheets automatically, is that possible?

Comment: ok, so need plot age column. This column is in each sheet and need concat all columns to one big? what is your original code? Can you explain more? Or if data are not confidental, can you send it to my email in  my profile and explain desired output?

Comment: okay i can send you a mock up data. i'll also send what i have done so far.

Comment: i just sent them. Thank you very much.